# Lifetime issue when implementing Iterator

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

I was implementing the `Iterator` trait for several structs and encountered some problems. Why is implementing `Iterator` for `Rows` shows error?
Here is a link: [link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=41cd51f3c4837f5ffaea&version=stable)

Basically why this doesn't work?

```
struct Stripe<'a> {
    cells: &'a [u32],
}

struct Rows<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
    vec: Vec<u32>,
    first: bool,
}

impl<'a> std::iter::Iterator for Rows<'a> {
    type Item = Stripe<'a>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Stripe<'a>> {
        if self.first {
            self.first = false;
            Some(
                Stripe {
                    cells: &self.vec[0..1],
                }
            )
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try

Comment: And make sure that your code is an [MCVE](/help/mcve). You should be able to remove all fluff that is not *directly* relevant to your question.

Comment: So I redused my code, is this readable enough?

Comment: almost, the `Foo` type and field is irrelevant for this problem, and is the source of the confusion imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifetime `'a` in the `Row` type refers only to one field of the type. The references you are returning have nothing to do with that lifetime. The `Iterator` trait does not allow you to return lifetimes into the iterator-object itself. That would require adding a new lifetime to the `next` function.

I suggest you create a `RowsIterator` type with a reference to your `Rows` object and handle the iterator-specific stuff in there:

```
struct Stripe<'a> {
    cells: &'a [u32],
}

struct Rows {
    vec: Vec<u32>,
}

struct RowsIter<'a> {
    rows: &'a Rows,
    first: bool,
}

impl<'a> std::iter::Iterator for RowsIter<'a> {
    type Item = Stripe<'a>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Stripe<'a>> {
        if self.first {
            self.first = false;
            Some(
                Stripe {
                    cells: &self.rows.vec[0..1],
                }
            )
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Full example in the [playground](http://is.gd/zupXNo)

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helped. But I still have a problem, because I actually need type Foo, but I guess I can cope with it by myself.

Comment: Thank you for the full example, didn't notice it at first.

Comment: you could actually separate the lifetimes of the `foo` reference of `Rows` and the lifetime of the `rows` reference of `RowsIter`, but most likely you don't need that. I simply used the same lifetime for both in the full example. See here for an example where the lifetimes are different: http://is.gd/hb09uj

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe you could look at this code and explain why implementation for Foo works, but it doesn't work for FooMut? Link:  [http://is.gd/5sCMHV ]

Comment: because if you call `next` twice, you'd end up with two mutable references to the same object

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense to me now.